# Computing metric matrix for a batch of data

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a set of features for my data like F, and there are different batches, I want to compute the following:

[image: U]

Where f_i corrosponding features to data point i, since I have a batch, my output matrix U is also has different batches, this is my code for that using torch.einsum, but I don't know why this is quite slow when I train it on GPU, I'm looking for a way to write the code in a vectorized manner with broadcasting or torch.bmm instead of that.

```
import torch

batch_size = 10
data_point_num = 9
features_num = 3
F = torch.randn(batch_size, data_point_num, features_num)
M = torch.randn(3, 3)

F_expanded = F[:, :, None, :]

diff = F_expanded - F[:, None, :, :]
U = torch.einsum('bijk,kl,bijl->bij', diff, M, diff)
```

Here is the code I tried to write, but the output shape of U is [10,81,81] which is clearly wrong, it should be [10,9,9]

```
batch_size = 10
data_point_num = 9
features_num = 3
M = torch.randn(features_num, features_num)
F = torch.randn(batch_size, data_point_num, features_num)
F_expanded = F[:, :, None, :]

diff = F_expanded - F[:, None, :, :]

diffall=diff.reshape((batch_size,data_point_num**2,features_num))
Mall=M.unsqueeze(0).repeat(batch_size,1,1)
A=torch.bmm(diffall,Mall)
U=torch.bmm(A,diffall.transpose(-1,-2))
```